# android no such table error

Tags: android, sqlite

I was stuck in the middle of no such table error while I created a database class. The logcat said that no such table. I have been trying to solve with several ways and unfortunately still got an error. Followings are the codes and Error is

> **android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tbl_category: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE idx = 1**

```
public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private static Context myContext;
public static final String DB_NAME = "ykko.db";

public static final String name = "name";
public static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.bit.ykko/databases/";

public DatabaseManager(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    DatabaseManager.myContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExit = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExit) {

    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase().getPath();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        Log.v("Path", myPath);
        checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }

    if (checkDb != null) {
        checkDb.close();
    }
    return checkDb != null ? true : false;
}

public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    InputStream databaseInput = null;
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream databaseOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;

    databaseInput = myContext.getAssets().open("ykko.sqlite");
    while ((length = databaseInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        databaseOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        databaseOutput.flush();
    }
    databaseInput.close();

    databaseOutput.flush();
    databaseOutput.close();
}

public void openDatabase() throws SQLiteException {

    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

public ArrayList<ChineseInfo> getCatByIdx(int idx) {
    ArrayList<ChineseInfo> list = new ArrayList<ChineseInfo>();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE idx = " + idx;

    Cursor c = this.db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ChineseInfo ch = new ChineseInfo();
            ch.idx = c.getInt(0);
            ch.name = c.getString(1);
            ch.mm_name = c.getString(2);
            list.add(ch);

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    if (c != null && !c.isClosed()) {
        c.close();
    }
    return list;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: Check the code you created this table.. "tbl_category".. i think there is some problem in that code.. like wrong name..probably..

Comment: Hi raju, I already double checked table name and table name is correct. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by myself. The error only happening in emulators.It is work fine at real devices.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you create database in memory and then copy paste it? If you want to have a database on sd card, simply create a database in sd card from the begining:

```
File sdpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String dbPath = sdpath.getAbsolutePath() + "/my_dir/mydb.sqlitedb";
SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below.

```
   private dbhelper mydbhelper;
   public static SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

... 

      public Cursor getData(int Id){
          return myDataBase.query("tbl_category", new String[]{"_id", "column1", "column2", "column3",},
                  "_id" + " = " + Id, null, null, null, null);}
```

Then call in you activity like below

```
            Cursor cursor = mydbhelper.getData(Id);
```